# Create a table inside a oracle a Job

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to extract some data from a very big table. Since the size of this table it takes very long time to complete a select query for that table. So I decided to create a new temporary table from inside a job (scheduler) for desired select statement and let it be run and get the output from that. Here is the code inside my job.

```
begin
    create table nwn_tmp_3133030 as
    select serial_number, item_code
    from   havy_table
    where id = '8800';
end;
```

But when I run the JOB it ended with below error.

```
"ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use dynamic SQL:

```
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'{create table nwn_tmp_3133030 as
select serial_number, item_code
from havy_table
where id = '8800'}';
end;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=062cc523a6221c46e3b5dec92048a4f4)**

---

EDIT:

You could also consider using [Private Temporary Table(Oracle 18c)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/newft/new-features.html#GUID-FE892CE2-E0EB-4D5B-9021-9D4D694FD99E);

Comment: well, that is how it would be done if one were insistent on perpetuating bad design.  I'm sure this is common in the mssql world, but in the oracle world, global temporary tables were designed specifically to avoid this kind of creating "temporary" tables on the fly, just for use by a single process.

Comment: @EdStevens Thank you for your comment. Temporary tables are handy mechanism,and Oracle supports them as well [Private Temporary Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/newft/new-features.html#GUID-FE892CE2-E0EB-4D5B-9021-9D4D694FD99E) -  *"Private temporary tables are temporary database objects that are automatically dropped at the end of a transaction or a session. A private temporary table is stored in memory and is visible only to the session that created it."* - just for use by a single process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a table on the fly like this.  If you want to go this route, just create a global temporary table (GTT).  That's a one-time setup.

But beyond that, I don't see how you are saving any time.  You complain about having to read the entire table, but then you do exactly that to load the data into you 'temporary' table.  Well, you DO qualify that with a WHERE clause - which may or may not avoid a full table scan, but why can't you apply that directly in your actual app code?